# Indent line ranges with sed?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I'm trying here to convert old fashion `phpBB` code blocks to `MARKDOWN` using `sed`.

Please consider following data sample:

```
cat sed.txt
[code]xxxx-YYY-xxxx[/code]
Some text
[code]yyyy-ZZZ-yyyy[/code]
More text
Bogus code block[/code]
[code]zzzz-XXX-zzzz[/code]
```

After long trial and error I've ended up with the following strategy:

```
sed -ne '
  /\[code\].*\[\/code\]/ {
  s#\[/*code\]##g
  s#^#\n\n    #
  s#$#\n\n#p
}' sed.txt | cat -Av
$
$
    xxxx-YYY-xxxx$
$
$
$
$
    yyyy-ZZZ-yyyy$
$
$
$
$
    zzzz-XXX-zzzz$
$
$
```

This works great, however I find it would be easier and seem more natural to do it this way:

```
sed -ne '
/\[code\].*\[\/code\]/ {
  s#\[/*code\]#\n\n#g
  s#^#    #p
}' sed.txt | cat -Av
    $
$
xxxx-YYY-xxxx$
$
$
    $
$
yyyy-ZZZ-yyyy$
$
$
    $
$
zzzz-XXX-zzzz$
$
$
```

But that does not work as expected. Any suggestions why, how to get around this?

Thank you

Comment: As shown in my current strategy code sample. I just don't understand why other code sample yields different results - xxxx,yyyy,zzzz lines are not indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr 's/^\[(code\])(.*)\[\/\1$/\n\n    \2\n\n/p' file | sed -n l
```

N.B. In your script you prepend 2 newlines to the beginning of the pattern space and then prepend 4 spaces again, thus the indentation is added infront of the first of the newlines not infront of the text.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path. I have finally figured out how to manipulate pattern & hold space to get same results: `sed -nr '/\[code\].*\[\/code\]/{s/\[\/*code\]//g;s/^/    /;h;s/.*/\n/;G;s/(.*)/\1\n\n/};p' sed.txt | sed -n l`. Also I've accepted your answer as it looks like the most elegant.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/\[code\].*\[\/code\]/ {
   s#\[code]#&    #g
   s#\[/*code\]#\
\
#g
   }' sed.txt
```

order of substitution is important and changed between your two sample

I also change a bit the behavior, the `-n` and `p` are not needed in this text sample (but maybe if coming from a biggest structure)
(test on my aix so posix version)

Comment: This does not reproduce desired result, note 2 empty lines above and below matched one.

Comment: your first sample is missing 2 ending line normaly (on my system it is and the sed specify $ ->\n\n so end is 2 empty line). Test with both code giving the same result here. But i forget the range filtering (added to my post)

Comment: OK, thank you, now it does reproduce desired results (alternative way to do, what I've done in my first code sample). *But it still does not answer my question* - **why second code sample does not work**, by my understanding they should be equivalent. In my initial post 2 ending lines were missing because of my fat fingers while editing, please see updated version.

Comment: the cycle of substitution is not the same, you add a `    ` at the end of current buffer on last action but not on each end of line and because there are at least 2 new line in the buffer, you miss them